# How to broadcast messages to specific room using MongoDb Object id instead of socket id

Tags: reactjs, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using nodejs and react to join rooms and want to broadcast a message to all users inside a room. I use here mongodb ID to connect to the rooms persistently.

The issue is I don't get the broadcast message when connect to the specific room.

***1. I created the join room server event***
This event will be used individually by frontend, depending of how many rooms there are joined by the user

```
//Backend join room
socket.on('join_room', (data: UserJoiningRoomData) => {
        socket.join(data.roomMongoDBObjectId);
        socket.to(data.roomMongoDBObjectId).emit('new_message', { 
            message: `${data.userJoining} just joined the chat`
        });
    });

//Frontend Join room
iterate over the room array got from the backend, and emit the join room event 
 // Handle the rooms data received from the server
    useEffect(() => {
        // Set up the event listener for 'user_rooms'
        socket.on('user_rooms', roomsData => {
            setRooms(roomsData);
        });


        // If rooms data is available, join each room
            rooms.forEach(room => {
                socket.emit('join_room', {
                    roomMongoDBObjectId: room._id,
                    userJoining: userState._id
                });
            });
    
        // Clean up the listener
        return () => {
            socket.off('user_rooms');
        };
    }, [rooms]);
```

***2. I created the `incomingMessage` event:***

```
    export type IncomingMessageType = {
    roomMongoDBObjectId: string,
    message: string,
    author: string 
}

    // broadcast a message to the room
    socket.on('incomingMessage', (data: IncomingMessageType) => {
        io.to(data.roomMongoDBObjectId).emit('new_message', {
            message:    data.message,
            author:     data.author
        });
    });
```

***3. Emit `incomingMessage` event from frontend and `new_message`***

```
 socket.on('new_message', data => {
        console.log(data)
        setMessageList(prevMessages => [...prevMessages, data]);
    })
    

    const handleSendMessage = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        socket.emit('incomingMessage', {
            roomMongoDBObjectId:    roomObject.roomObj._id,
            message:                messageInput.value,
            author:                 roomObject.author    
        })
        messageInput.value = ''; 
    }
```